# How can I figure out what application keeps stealing the focus on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find out which application is stealing focus in Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/28322/how-can-i-find-out-which-application-is-stealing-focus-in-vista)

Recently some application has started stealing the focus. I'll be typing normally and all of a sudden the application is no longer active. It happens to all programs and started today, but I haven't installed anything recently.

How can I figure out what application is doing this?

Comment: Have you considered trying a Windows System Restore to a point in time before today to see if it keeps happening?  What becomes active when the current window loses focus?  If this is an notebook with a track pad, ensure your thumb isn't hitting it while typing. :)

Comment: Play a video with media player classic home cinema in full-screen. When it grabs, MPC will show the app's name.